# Android ViewModel DI dependency injection error

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, viewmodel

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel
@Inject constructor(private val authRepository: AuthRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val _hidePassword = MutableLiveData(false)
    val hidePassword: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _hidePassword


    private val _autoLogin = MutableLiveData(false)
    val autoLogin: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _autoLogin

    private val _loginError = MutableLiveData(false)

    val loginError: LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _loginError


    fun login(userId: String, password: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            kotlin.runCatching {
                authRepository.login(
                    LoginReqeustDto(
                        userId = userId,
                        password = password
                    )
                )
            }.onSuccess {
//                val prefs = NewJeansBunniesApplication.prefs
//                prefs.accessToken = it.accessToken
//                prefs.autoLogin = autoLogin.value?:false
//                if(autoLogin.value == true)
//                    prefs.refreshToken = it.refreshToken
//                _loginError.value = false
            }.onFailure { e ->
                _loginError.value = true
                Log.d("LoginViewModel", e.message.toString())
            }
        }
    }

    fun loginError(status: Boolean) {
        _loginError.value = status
    }

    fun autoLogin(status: Boolean) {
        _autoLogin.value = status
    }

    fun hidePassword(status: Boolean) {
        _hidePassword.value = status
    }

}
```

If I leave out private val authRepository: AuthRepository, it works normally, but if I put in private val authRepository: AuthRepository, it says Cannot create an instance of class newjeans.bunnies.auth.viewmodel.LoginViewModel.

Perhaps the problem occurred in the code below.

```kotlin
interface AuthApi {
    @POST("/api/auth/login")
    suspend fun login(
        @Body loginRequestDto: LoginReqeustDto
    ): LoginResponseDto

    @POST("/api/auth/signup")
    suspend fun signup(
        @Body signupRequestDto: SignupReqeustDto
    ): SignupResponseDto

    @PATCH("/api/auth")
    suspend fun refresh(
        @Header("refresh-token") token: String
    )
}
```

```kotlin
class ApiRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val authApi: AuthApi
) : AuthRepository {
    override suspend fun login(loginRequestDto: LoginReqeustDto): LoginResponseDto {
        return authApi.login(loginRequestDto)
    }

    override suspend fun signup(signupRequestDto: SignupReqeustDto): SignupResponseDto {
        return authApi.signup(signupRequestDto)
    }

    override suspend fun refresh(token: String) {
        return authApi.refresh(token)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
interface AuthRepository {
    suspend fun login(loginRequestDto: LoginReqeustDto): LoginResponseDto
    suspend fun signup(signupRequestDto: SignupReqeustDto): SignupResponseDto
    suspend fun refresh(token: String)
}
```

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class RepositoryModel {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAuthRepository(apiRepositoryImpl: ApiRepositoryImpl): AuthRepository =
        apiRepositoryImpl

}
```

```kotlin
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideAuthApi(retrofit: Retrofit): AuthApi =
    retrofit.create(AuthApi::class.java)
```

I checked the version and tried using hiltViewModel.

Comment: Post relevant exception stack trace, not just the message.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure without a stack trace, but I see a problem with a way you're providing your repository. You may check out [this](https://www.valueof.io/blog/inject-provides-binds-dependencies-dagger-hilt) article or something [similar](https://medium.com/@seungbae2/understanding-the-difference-between-provides-and-binds-in-android-hilt-88d210e358d9).

So basically, to map your interface with your implementation, you have to use @Binds instead. Or if you want to use @Provides instead, it would have a different look. Something like that with @Binds:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
interface RepositoryModel {

    @Binds
    fun provideAuthRepository(apiRepositoryImpl: ApiRepositoryImpl): AuthRepository
}
```

Or with @Provides

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class RepositoryModel {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAuthRepository(authApi: AuthApi): AuthRepository =
        ApiRepositoryImpl(authApi)

}
```

Comment: And I hope, you did provide what is a "retrofit" (at least it's not included here in the code, so I'm just assuming), otherwise Hilt doesn't know what a pokemon is that and how to create it